# XUnit how to fake a private method that returns data (Not Testing Private Method)

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, xunit

I have a dotnet 3.1 core web api application and looking to use xUnit. In this, I am only wanting to test the public methods, BUT I do have several private methods that either make a call to a database to return data or make a rest call to an external service.

**Question:**
I am **NOT** trying to test the private method, but how can I fake the return data of the private methods, so that when my public method calls the private method, I can return a fake set of data so that my public method and calculations can be tested?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**
Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
public class FooRepository{
   public MyObject CalculateValues{
      var myReturnObject = new MyObject();
      var crewSalaries = GetCrewSalaries(myCrew)

      myObject.TotalSalary = crewSalaries.Sum(x=>x.salary)
      // Insert other calculations here
   }
   private MyObject GetCrewSalaries(List<Crew> myCrew){
      return dbContext.Where(x=>x.id == myCrew.id).ToList();
   }
}

Public Class FooRepositoryTest{
 [Fact]
 public Test1()
 {
   var fooClass = new fooClass();
   // mock or hijack fooClass.GetCrewSalaries, so that I can return fake data
   var result = fooClass.CalculateValues();

   // assert statement here
 }

 private GetFakeSalaryData()
 {
  return new List<CrewSalaries>{
     [
       id:1,
       salary:23
     ],
     [
       id:2,
       salary:23.1
     ],
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: Hey Nkosi, just updated it! I should have done that to begin with.

Comment: Right. Current code has tight coupling to implementation concerns that make isolating the desired behavior difficult. The shown example still lacks the details about the dependencies to be able to better provide you with a more targeted answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what dependencies you are referring to?  I'm just needing to know how can I catch when GetCrewSalaries gets called and return my own set of data?

Comment: You can't. Not without refactoring that code. You show a call to a `dbContext`. How does that get into the class. You do not show that. With an incomplete example, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Solution is there: [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12074/28425](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12074/28425)

Comment: @Nkosi sorry, everything not listed is passed in through dependency injection.

I'm seein ga lot about refactoring those calls into a small class that has an interface. Is that what is recommended?

Comment: @Godrules500 that tends to be the most recommended approach.